# different page direct depending on if field is empty

Tags: php, mysql

Please help! This is my code where I am trying to set mandatory fields. If the field is empty it should display the error if its been completed, it should redirect to myaccount.php. With the code below it is just redirecting me to myaccount.php all the time. the field in question is a large text area.
PHP:

```
session_start();
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$err = array();
if (isset($_POST['doThesis']) && $_POST['doThesis'] == 'Save')
{
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    exit(header("Location:login.php\r\n"));
}

{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE `banned` = '0'") or 
die (mysql_error());



list($id) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

$_SESSION['user_id']= $id;
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)

if(empty($abstract))
{
$err[] = "ERROR - Enter Native Language";
//    header("Location: language.php?msg=$err[0]");
}

/// Automatically collects the hostname or domain  like example.com)
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$host_upper = strtoupper($host);
$path   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');

if(empty($err)) {
    $thesis_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thesis_Name']);
    $abstract = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abstract']);

$sql_insert = "INSERT into `thesis`
    (`user_id`,`thesis_Name`,`abstract` )
VALUES
    ('$id','$thesis_Name','$abstract') ";

mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());
}
header("Location: myaccount.php?id=' . $_SESSION[user_id] .'");
exit();

}
}
```

Login form:

```
$err = array();

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
$get[$key] = filter($value); //get variables are filtered.
}

if (@$_POST['doLogin']=='Login')
{

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
$data[$key] = filter($value); // post variables are filtered
}


$user_email = $data['usr_email'];
$pass = $data['pwd'];


if (strpos($user_email,'@') === false) {
$user_cond = "user_name='$user_email'";
} else {
$user_cond = "user_email='$user_email'";

}


$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`pwd`,`full_name`,`approved`,`user_level` FROM users
  WHERE 
       $user_cond
        AND `banned` = '0'
        ") or die (mysql_error()); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

// Match row found with more than 1 results  - the user is authenticated. 
if ( $num > 0 ) { 

list($id,$pwd,$full_name,$approved,$user_level) = mysql_fetch_row($result);


//header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
 //exit();
 }

if(empty($err)){            

 // this sets session and logs user in  
    session_start();
   session_regenerate_id (true); //prevent against session fixation attacks.

   // this sets variables in the session 
    $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

    //update the timestamp and key for cookie
    $stamp = time();
    $ckey = GenKey();
    mysql_query("update users set `ctime`='$stamp', `ckey` = '$ckey' 
where id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

    //set a cookie 


    header("Location: myaccount.php?id=' . $_SESSION[user_id] .'");
    exit();
     }
    }
    else
    {
    //$msg = urlencode("Invalid Login. Please try again with correct 
user email and password. ");
    $err[] = "Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email
and password.";
    //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
    }
} else {
    $err[] = "Error - Invalid login. No such user exists";
  }
```

}

Comment: Why are you reassigning $_SESSION['user_id'] with a value?

Comment: I just want the session to stay from the user logging into and then clicking this page so the id of my users table is the user_id in the thesis table.

Comment: @user1257518: try now i fixed the code. it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - not testest but should be something like this:

```
<?php
$err = array();

// if not logged in no reason to go further
if (empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: signup.php');
    // or login.php
}

// otherwise
if (isset($_POST['doThesis'])) {
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
    $user_id = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);
    // check if current user is banned
    $the_query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE `banned` = '0' AND `id` = '%d'", $user_id);
    $result = mysql_query($the_query, $link);
    if ($result) {
        $user_check = mysql_num_rows($result);
        // user is ok
        if ($user_check > 0) {

            // required field name goes here...
            $required_fields = array('thesis_Name');
            // check for empty fields
            foreach ($required_fields as $field_name) {
                $value = trim($_POST[$field_name]);
                if (empty($value)) {
                    $err[] = "ERROR - $field_name is left blank!";
                }
            }
            // no errors
            if (empty($err)) {

                $thesis_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thesis_Name']);
                $abstract = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abstract']);

                // insert into the database
                $the_query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `thesis` (`user_id`,`thesis_Name`,`abstract`) VALUES ('%d','%s','%s')", $user_id, $thesis_Name, $abstract);

                // query is ok?
                if (mysql_query($the_query, $link)) {

                    // redirect to user profile
                    header('Location: myaccount.php?id=' . $user_id);
                } else {
                    echo mysql_error();
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Still not calling session_start() before testing if $_SESSION['user_id'] :)

Comment: i tried your work @aSeptik and get the warning `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\thesis.php on line 21`

Comment: @user1257518: sorry my bad i have missed to add the $link, try now

Comment: same message and doesnt sent data to database

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\thesis.php on line 21

Comment: Thanks that works but if if i keep the check login it just redirects me to my login page. Ive deleted that. but get the message Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\thesis.php on line 14 then

Comment: this mean that the $_SESSION is not defined elsewhere. you need to post to us the code you use for the login form. the problem is there most probably.

Comment: @user1257518: i'm glad that you finally understand **where** ( in your login script ) to put the session_start(). ;-)

Comment: the only thing is not all fields are required fields, but your code shows every code that is left empty

Comment: @user1257518: i have added the $required_fields array and changed the loop, look at it for understand how it work, very simple. if you want you can also vote-up for sake! ;-) thank's

Answer (score 5):

The first issue I can see is that you're checking for a session value before calling session_start();

Move the session_start(); to the top of the page and see if that helps at all

```
<?php
    session_start();
    .....
```

This looks wrong for two reasons I can see

```
if (empty($_SESSION['$user_id'])) { }
```

First off, there's a $ in there, is that meant to be there?

Secondly, it wraps all the rest of the code in your page and doesn't actually do what I think you want it to do.

Try this instead

```
if (isset($_POST['doThesis']) && $_POST['doThesis'] == 'Save')
{
    if ( ! isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
        exit(header("Location: someotherpage.php\r\n"));
    }
    // the rest of your code
}
```

I had another look through your code and I would suggest going through it again yourself.

It seems you are checking if $_SESSION['user_id'] is set and the you are reassigning it a new value from a quite 'loose' sql "SELECT id FROM users WHERE banned = 0", How do you know which id is going to be returned from this?

Comment: I'll have another look, give me a few mins

Comment: ive edited my code above to your suggestions but still doing the same

Comment: I would suggest checking whether or not a user is banned at login time, then you can totally remove the check from this code, assuming the user has to be logged in at this point. Break the script down into small logical steps and give it another crack. Can always ask us again if you need to :)

Comment: to be honest that was some code that was suggested to me that was to help with keeping the session. I can get rid of it? I'm a total newbie so really struggling

Comment: if you have some form of login, you can run an sql along these lines: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}' AND password = '{$password}' AND banned = 0"" Where $email and $password are your form variables, then in the page we're talking about that check can be totally removed because they wouldn't have been able to login in the first place.

Comment: removing that line, data is sent to the database

Comment: Excellent! Just make sure you keeping things secure, and whenever you are using session data always put session_start(); at the top, there are a few cases where you don't need to but it's generally a good idea to have it as the first thing.

Comment: sorry I meant isn't being sent. trying to declare the variables now

Comment: @Dale: i really like to guess! ;-)